# Simpler way to display multi array vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I am not really sure whether this problem comes under multi array or not.

I have some set of values mentioned below

For 1 hr in 100 °C -> 2516 
For 2 hr in 100 °C -> 2566 
For 1 hr in 200 °C -> 2344 
For 2 hr in 200 °C -> 2156

There are 50 to 60 records like this.. And I will enter everything manually in the code something like array..

What will be the best way to retrieve the values

For Eg: If I give 2 hr and 100 °C -> Result should be 2566

For more clear I am attaching one screen shots below

[Software UI and Charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8sVU.png)

I have embedded Charts below the UI screen itself and there are more charts like that..

If I select radio button 100 °C With 1 Hr. then the Output will be

B.H -> M21(2516) & NC(2573) 
A.H -> M21(2512) & NC(2567) 
Loss -> M21(0.159) & NC(0.2332)

Sorry if I am not good with English or else with Explanation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven't written any code. I have just designed the UI and written some conditions.. Right now I have to form that data as some sort of array and I should display it @Icemanind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with Dictionary, since this instruction can work with an index and a value. See if this can helps you:
http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-vbnet

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried it but I am not able to understand how to store this values. Can you store any one value from the above chart I have attached. That could help me more. @david-bs

Comment: @SathvikChinnu, suppose you have 8 dictionaries, each one representing a tmeperature (100, 200, 300 and so forth).  In each one you create an index to represent a SPECIFIC TEMPERATURE and it's value. Since Dictionaries work with an index, you can have several records of same indexes with the corresponding value. To print the table you just have to access each Dict, sort it by INDEX and after, print the values.

Comment: Thank you @DavidBS